# How best to search for dependencies?

Tags: dependencies

mpv has a lot of [dependencies](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/#compilation) and I don't know how to search for them. Is there a way to search for the packages that contain the dependencies?

Comment: `mpv` is available from the universe repository. `apt depends mpv` should give you the depends for mpv on your system.

Comment: Why do you wish to search for dependencies? Apt takes care of everything for you...if you are using it properly.

Comment: You have lots of options. See [How to list dependent packages (reverse dependencies)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128524/how-to-list-dependent-packages-reverse-dependencies?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)  `apt depends` works, but you can install `rdepends` and then use `apt-rdepends -r <packagename>`, may give a more thorough list...There's also `apt-cache showpkg <packagename>`. Or `ubuntu-dev-tools` provides `reverse-depends`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list dependent packages (reverse dependencies)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128524/how-to-list-dependent-packages-reverse-dependencies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following commands show information about a package (`mpv` in this case), including dependencies.

- `aptitude show mpv`
- `apt show mpv`

The following command shows dependencies recursively (the depends of depends of...):

- `apt-rdepends mpv`

The following commands show reverse dependencies (packages for which this package is a dependency):

- `apt rdepends mpv`
- `apt-rdepends -r mpv`

The following command shows both dependencies and reverse dependencies:

- `apt-cache showpkg mpv`

If you just want to install a package and have the package manager handle dependencies, use:

```
`aptitude install mpv`
```

`aptitude` automatically resolves conflicting dependencies during installation, whereas `apt`/`apt-get` do not.