# How to Display .HEIC thumbnails in Nautilus?

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, filemanager, thumbnails

What are the steps to configure 16.04's Nautilus file manager to display thumbnails of [.HEIC photos](https://www.macworld.co.uk/feature/iphone/what-is-heic-3660408/)?

```
file IMG_1001.HEIC
IMG_1001.HEIC: ISO Media
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] your question to include the output of `file filename.heic` where the filename.heic is one of the files in question. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: It's simple for Ubuntu 19.04 and later. Just install heif-thumbnailer package. But for 16.04...

Comment: Definitely easier after 19.04, see https://askubuntu.com/a/965306/25520 for the progression

Answer (score 1):

As the title no longer suggest 16.04, I can now provide the link to the question which works for me [HEIF/HEIC Thumbnail issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299029/heif-heic-thumbnail-issue)

In short:

```
sudo apt-get install libheif1 heif-thumbnailer
```