# How to transfer data from iPhone XS to Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: 19.04, iphone

I want to transfer all the photos on my iPhone (XS, iOS 12.4) to my computer (Ubuntu 19.04) but when I plug in my iPhone to the pc, I can't see the photos like I used to see when I was using a Windows pc. In addition, I couldn't find any application like iTunes for Ubuntu. I would be glad if you guys know a way out.

Comment: Do you can access to DCIM folders? IOS use HEVC format for photos https://askubuntu.com/questions/958355/any-app-on-ubuntu-to-open-heif-heic-high-efficiency-image-file-format-pictur

Comment: I can't see DCIM folders