# How to display photo thumbnails of .heic file in Xfce?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, heic

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 with Xfce desktop environment and the thumbnails of my .heic files are not showing. I can see the pictures in Image viewer, but not on the thumbnails and I'm bothered by that.

I have already tried what's suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1298597/1382215) : heif-gdk-pixbuf, heif-thumbnailer and libheif1 are correctly installed and no error pop in the terminal. However, no thumbnail is showing. How can I fix this?

Comment: It might be the File Manager that you're using in Xfce. See if it works in Nautilus.

Comment: It works with Nautilus! Waw, it seems simple but I wouldn't have thought of that. Thanks! Can you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How to view .HEIC photos from iPhone IOS 11+ on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298595/how-to-view-heic-photos-from-iphone-ios-11-on-ubuntu/1298597#1298597) to get info on what software you need to install to view .HEIC images.

You're using a File Manager in Xfce that won't display these thumbnails.

Use Nautilus File Manager and you'll see the thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

Xfce by default has file manager Thunar and thumbnail generator service [Tumbler](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/tumbler/start). Tumbler is extensible, by adding thumbnailers,
thumbnails for more types of files can be generated and shown in Thunar, one can also add one's own to generate thumbnails for all kinds of files as one desire.

Installing `heif-thumbnailer` adds the file `/usr/share/thumbnailers/heif.thumbnailer`, with `image/heif;` listed after `MimeType=`. This should be picked up by Tumbler automatically. This can be confirmed by running the program `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tumbler-1/tumblerd` manually, it should contain a line like

> Registered thumbnailer heif-thumbnailer -s %s %i %o

Try having only `heif-thumbnailer` installed but *not* `heif-gdk-pixbuf`. It may just work.

This may sound strange but installing `heif-gdk-pixbuf` may not add heif support to thumbnail generators like Tumbler. Further, possibly because of bugs, it may even prevent `heif-thumbnailer` from working with Tumbler.

Theoretically, Tumbler, with the included plugin Pixbuf-thumbnailer, should be able to generate thumbnails for the plurality of file types gdk-pixbuf supports.

gdk-pixbuf is modular and can be extended by installing additional *loaders*, such as `heif-gdk-pixbuf`, which adds heif support. Using the program `gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer` from the package `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin`, one can verify that given an heif image, a thumbnail can be generated.

However, by inspecting the file `/usr/share/thumbnailers/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer.thumbnailer`, one finds that heif doesn't seem to be listed among supported `MimeType`s. So thumbnailers like `Tumbler` may fail to recognize the capabilities added to gdk-pixbuf.

And when I have both `heif-thumbnailer` and `heif-gdk-pixbuf` installed, heif thumbnailing stops working. Through trial and error, I seem to find something wrong with `JPEGThumbnailer` that comes with tumbler. Although it should be only for JPEG files, installed libraries may be interacting in unexpected ways. One can see from `/etc/xdg/tumbler/tumbler.rc` that it has a high priority: `Priority=3`. So if you need `heif-gdk-pixbuf` for purposes other than thumbnailing, you may try to avoid the `JPEGThumbnailer` of tumbler by overwriting its priority in the file `~/.config/tumbler/tumbler.rc` with:

```
[JPEGThumbnailer]
Priority=1
```

or you can just disable it, it's not the only provider of JPEG thumbnails:

```
Disabled=true
```

Upcoming versions will try to keep trying multiple thumbnailers, so the situation will hopefully get better: https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/tumbler/-/issues/50