# How can I easily install kimageformat-plugins_5.90.0 from Jammy in Impish?

Tags: 21.10, image-viewers, gwenview, heic

How can I easily install `kimageformat-plugins_5.90.0` from Jammy in Kubuntu 21.10 which has `kimageformat-plugins/impish,now 5.86.0`? Kubuntu 21.10 isn't able to display HEIF/HEIC images from iPhone.

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 21.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.22.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.86.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-27-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz
Memory: 15.4 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 530
```

Comment: Please check if the answers of this question work for you. https://askubuntu.com/q/958355/124466

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi From another post it seems this is still not supported even in 21.10. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337954/heif-heic-support-in-kubuntu-21-04

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1375987/124466