# could not display "picture name"

Tags: 22.04, .desktop

im new to this and ubuntu and i was trying to save some pictures from my mothers phone. I did everything like on windows until i got an popup saying "could not display "picture name"" and bellow "theres no aplication installed for "heif image" files. Do you want to search for an aplication to open this file." so i opened ubuntu software and downloaded PhotoQT. Got back to the file and tried to open it with PhotoQT, nothing bloody happens and now im stuck here with nothing to open these pictures. Please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZHzT.png)

Comment: This might help you: [Any app on Ubuntu to open and/or convert HEIF pictures (.HEIC, High Efficiency Image File Format)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958355/any-app-on-ubuntu-to-open-and-or-convert-heif-pictures-heic-high-efficiency-i)