How to view iPhone .heic Images after iOS 18 update in Ubuntu 24.04?
In Kubuntu 24.04 I'm no longer able to view iPhone .HEIC images after I've installed iOS 18 on my iPhone. In Gwenview I get the error:

Loading image failed.

In GIMP I get the error:

Loading HEIF image failed: Invalid input: Unspecified: Metadata not correctly assigned to image.

ImageMagick, same type of error:

Invalid input: Unspecified: Metadata not correctly assigned to image.

Suggestions from this older Kubuntu 21.04 thread no longer work. How do I view iPhone iOS 18 sourced .HEIC images in Kubuntu 24.04? Is this also an issue with Ubuntu 24.04 or is it a KDE Plasma thing?

Does this work? https://askubuntu.com/q/958355/124466

@Archisman Panigrahi I did try that sudo apt-get install heif-gdk-pixbuf heif-thumbnailer but it doesn't work. It used to work, but after I upgraded to iOS 18 on my iPhone something broke and I can no longer view .HEIC on Kubuntu anymore.

I see. Can you still post one example photo (upload it to dropbox/GDrive and share the link) that we all can try to open and debug the issue?

@Archisman Panigrahi https://github.com/tigranbs/test-heic-images/raw/refs/heads/master/image1.heic is an .HEIC I can view in Kubuntu 24.04, along with pre-iOS-18 .HEIC photos. Post-iOS-18 .HEIC photos don't work and I can see this is an issue in other projects see (1) https://github.com/immich-app/immich/issues/10464 (2) https://github.com/strukturag/libheif/issues/1190. I think I might need to wait for upstream fixes to make it downstream to Kubuntu? Eventually? For now I just changed the settings on my iPhone from Save as .HEIC to Save as .jpg. Problem solved (but not really).

Try the libheif ppa which hosts an updated version of libheif (otherwise, later versions of libheif will only appear in the official repositories of later versions of Ubuntu. Non-security updates are not backported). Open a terminal and enter the following commands one by one.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/libheif
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install libheif
sudo apt install libheif-plugin-libde265 libheif-plugin-aomenc libgd3 libheif1

As per the GitHub issue, the version 1.18.2 in the PPA (as of 31st October 2024) should contain the fix for this issue.
Edit: I verified that it works with the latest version of libheif on Arch Linux. (I tested the example HEIC file in the GitHub issue). Therefore, updating libheif on Ubuntu should fix the issue as well.

A quick note for this answer which did work for me.
It's libheif1, not libheif. You may also have to force install the following due to apt not wanting to push dependencies. I had to use this to make it work.
sudo apt install libheif-plugin-libde265 libheif-plugin-aomenc libgd3 libheif1
Edited to fix extra enters which are plaguing me today.

This issue occurs with iOS 18, older versions are not affected.
We have to wait for official .heif update to work with.
Until then there is an unofficial build for libheif. Thanks to him, upgrade your current lib using following (ubuntu 24 comes with heif support)
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/libheif
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
If don't have heif (usually have),
sudo apt install heif-gdk-pixbuf - decoder and encoder
sudo apt install heif-thumbnailer - show thumbnails
sudo aptinstall libheif-examples - converter (heic2jpeg, etc.)
